# ValidarJFXTextField

Tags: java, javafx, validación

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicación en con **Java FX** con la libreria *JFONIX*
quiero validar un *JFXTesxtField* para que solo acapte números y otro para que acepte números decimales y que en este último no se puedan introducir mas de 1 `.`

```
public void SoloNumerosEnteros(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    try{
        char key = keyEvent.getCharacter().charAt(0);
        if(Character.isLetter(key))
            keyEvent.consume();

    }catch (Exception ex){  }
}
```

Archivo FXML:

```
<JFXTextField fx:id="TxtTel" focusColor="#3f8bad" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="194.0" style="-fx-text-inner-color: WHITE;" unFocusColor="#178bad" onKeyTyped="#SoloNumerosEnteros" />
```

Este mismo código en una aplicación Normal me funciona pero en esta (asumo yo) como `.consume();` no pertenece a la libreria `javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;` no hace nada el `.consume();`. Espero me puedan ayudar a solucionar estos problemas.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que "`consume()` no pertenece a la librería javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent"? ¿Qué significa que no hace nada?

Comment: Creo que me exprese mal. lo que quiero decir es que .consume no es un metodo el cual se encuentre en esa libreria (javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;)  y que por ende no puedo utilizar como metodo de keyEvent. ese codigo al ejecutarce deja ingresar letras y numeros sin diferenciarlos. A eso me refiero con que no hace nada (No puedo consmir el keyEvent)

Comment: Agrega el código donde utilizas el método `SoloNumerosEnteros()`, porque tal y como lo tienes programado, este debe evitar que se introduzcan letras.

Comment: <JFXTextField fx:id="TxtTel" focusColor="#3f8bad" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="194.0" style="-fx-text-inner-color: WHITE;" unFocusColor="#178bad" onKeyTyped="#SoloNumerosEnteros" /> Esta linea esta en un archivo fxml

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrégalo ahí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para agregar una validación en un campo de texto de JavaFX te recomiendo que lo hagas utilizando `EventHandlers` y desde el código. Si agregas en el SceneBuilder el método que se ejecutará cuando ocurra un evento, dicho método será llamado posterior a que el componente lo haya manejado, por lo que la llamada al `consume()` no tendrá el efecto esperado por ti.

Así lo haría yo

```
textField.setOnKeyTyped(event -> SoloNumerosEnteros(event));
```

**EDITADO:**
Por algún motivo que desconozco el código anterior no funciona en Java 9, quizás se trate de algún bug (mi versión es 9.0.1). Si trabajas con esta versión de Java utiliza el siguiente código en vez del anterior.

```
textField.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, event -> SoloNumerosEnteros(event));
```

***fin de la edición***

Adicionalmente te recomiendo utilizar `Character.isDigit()` en vez de `Character.isLetter()`, ya que por ejemplo un asterisco no es una letra y estaría permitido por tu método de validación.

```
public void SoloNumerosEnteros(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    try{
        char key = keyEvent.getCharacter().charAt(0);

        if (!Character.isDigit(key))
            keyEvent.consume();

    } catch (Exception ex){ }
}
```